# C# code cannot understand

Tags: c#

I have a question, because I am a coder of c++, now I need read some c# code. This is a class in a namespace, what I do not understand is the last member;

```
public string FilePath
{
            get { return this.filePath; }
            set { this.filePath = value; }
}
```

I do not know it is a member variable or a member function.

If see it as a member function, it should like

```
public string FilePath(***)
{
****;
}
```

but here it doesn't have a () similar parameter, what type of function is it?

```
  class INIFileOperation
    {
    private string filePath;

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string section,
    string key,
    string val,
    string filePath);

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section,
    string key,
    string def,
    StringBuilder retVal,
    int size,
    string filePath);

    public string ReadAppPath()
    {
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

        return appPath + "\\Setting.ini";
    }

    public INIFileOperation()
    {
        this.filePath = ReadAppPath();
    }

    public void Write(string section, string key, string value)
    {
        WritePrivateProfileString(section, key, value.ToUpper(), this.filePath);
    }
    public string Read(string section, string key)
    {
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder(255);
        int i = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, "", SB, 255, this.filePath);
        return SB.ToString();
    }
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return this.filePath; }
        set { this.filePath = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be useful for future reference: [C# for C++ programmers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view

```
public string FilePath
        {
            get { return this.filePath; }
            set { this.filePath = value; }
        }
```

as a kind of writing

```
public string GetFilePath() { return this.filePath; }
public string SetFilePath(string value_) { this.filePath = value_; }
```

but it gives you the so called `property` FilePath which can be used as `obj.FilePath="abc"`or `string abc = obj.FilePath`.

Answer (score 5):

This is not method but this is the ways c# allows to define properties of class.

**MSDN** *A property is a member that provides a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the value of a private field. Properties can be used as if they are public data members, but they are actually special methods called accessors. This enables data to be accessed easily and still helps promote the safety and flexibility of methods.*

- Properties enable a class to expose a public way of getting and
  setting values, while hiding implementation or verification code.
- A get property accessor is used to return the property value, and a
  set accessor is used to assign a new value. These accessors can have
  different access levels.
- The value keyword is used to define the value being assigned by the
  set accessor.
- Properties that do not implement a set accessor are read only.
- For simple properties that require no custom accessor code, consider
  the option of using auto-implemented properties

  ```
  public string FilePath
  {
       get 
       { 
           return this.filePath; 
       }
       set 
       { 
           this.filePath = value; 
       }
  }
  ```

*You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)*

Comment: if it is a property, then it seems still have method. get, set. Can post a using example of this class's FilePath Property invoving get and set?

Comment: get and set are special methods they are call when you access or set the value, you can write code to validate in set and perform calculations on get to return value, you can read more here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

FilePath is a public string variable belonging to the class it is found in. The get and set define the ways of getting and setting the variable when it is accessed.

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/lesson10